# Failed to load response data from API

Tags: reactjs, post

I am new to working with API and was given an assignment to get response data from the API in ReactJS.

The API given to me is this: [image: API]

To get the response from it I have tried this method and I'm not able to get the response from the API after posting data.

I think I might have been doing the mistake with sending the request using the inputs.

Is anyone aware of what exactly my mistake in getting the response from API and guide me solve this issue I'm facing with it.

Whatever ideas you feel that can be of help to me feel free to assist me. I'll give my sandbox link to further code reference of what I have done and ask me if anything you need regarding the code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-smvr6h?file=/src/Login.js

I think the mistake I have done is when I'm sending the post request to the API with the input parameters.